# Check read and unread message in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

If the user has not yet accessed the message, it remains bold ("unread") and the number should be show how many message unread . If the user clicks the link and accesses it, it goes from bold to unbold ("read")

[image]
.aspx code:

```
<li><a href="ContactForm.aspx"><span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-envelop"></span><span class="txt">Contact Forms</span></a><span class="notification" id="txtContactCount" runat="server">0</span></li>
```

c# code:

```
string ContactCount = system.GetDataCell("Select Count(*) from TBLCONTACTFORM");
txtContactCount.InnerText = ContactCount.ToString();
```

now its working but it show only total message

Comment: You will of course need to filter the results, `Select Count(*) from TBLCONTACTFORM WHERE status = 0` (I'm just guessing the `Status` and `0` are the unread indicators)

Comment: Im trying ur code but now it show 0

Comment: @Shkupjane What is the structure of `TBLCONTACTFORM`? Without that we can only speculate as to what the `WHERE` clause needs to be. How do you know at a db level that the message is unread?

Comment: i have status column in table, what's ur advice about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL `Select Count(*) from TBLCONTACTFORM` will count everything in that table. You need to add some sort of [`WHERE`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause on there.

Answer (score 0):

Select Count(*) from TBLCONTACTFORM Where ... 
add where condition.